# What can replace the test_database () function from playhouse.test_utils?

Tags: peewee

I want to use custom sqlite database for unit tests for code.
The answer to the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15982801/custom-sqlite-database-for-unit-tests-for-code-using-peewee-orm) uses `test_database` from `playhouse.test_utils`.

However, this is currently not available there.

What can I replace it with?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `Database.bind()` or `Database.bind_ctx()` methods, which are documented:

http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/api.html#Database.bind_ctx

The documentation covers this exact scenario:

```
MODELS = (User, Account, Note)

# Bind the given models to the db for the duration of wrapped block.
def use_test_database(fn):
    @wraps(fn)
    def inner(self):
        with test_db.bind_ctx(MODELS):
            test_db.create_tables(MODELS)
            try:
                fn(self)
            finally:
                test_db.drop_tables(MODELS)
    return inner


class TestSomething(TestCase):
    @use_test_database
    def test_something(self):
        # ... models are bound to test database ...
        pass
```